# JRuby: Redirecting stdout to StringWriter produces empty output

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I am using JRuby to dynamically run Ruby scripts from a Java program. The scripts receive arguments using ARGV and an object containing additional information called "ctx". They then do something with the information and return their result to stdout or, if something went wrong, an error message to stderr. This is the code I'm using to execute the ruby script:

```java
String script = Joiner.on('\n').join(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); // read file from 
script = "require 'rubygems'\n" + script; // make gems work

ScriptingContainer rb = new ScriptingContainer(LocalVariableBehavior.PERSISTENT);
rb.setCompatVersion(CompatVersion.RUBY1_9);

String cwd = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString();
rb.setCurrentDirectory(cwd); // set working directory of scripts to working directory of application

StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pwOut = new PrintWriter(out);

StringWriter err = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pwErr = new PrintWriter(err);

String[] argsAry = args.split(" ");

rb.setOutput(pwOut);
rb.setError(pwErr);
rb.setArgv(argsAry); // set output writer, error writer and argv

rb.put("ctx", ctx); // add ctx to script container

try {
    rb.runScriptlet(script);
} catch(Throwable t) {
    logger.error("An exception occurred during JRuby execution! (ctx-id=" +
            ctx.getId() + ")", t);
}

out.close();
err.close(); // close writers

System.out.println(out.getBuffer()); // for debugging purposes

System.err.println(err.getBuffer()); // print stderr result to stderr,
return out.getBuffer().toString(); // and return stdout result
```

This is the ruby script I'm using for testing:

```ruby
text = ARGV * ' '

puts text
```

Now my problem is that both buffers are completely empty after the execution of the ruby script. I just get two empty lines in stdout/err and nothing is returned. Using another script, I've made sure that the scripts do run and ctx is passed to the script successfully.

Things I've tried already:

- Using a variable inside ctx to pass the result to the java program, using `rb.get` to retrieve it - NullPointerException trying to access ctx
- Using a variable inside ctx, without using `rb.get` - variable is empty
- Setting a string in the script to pass it to the program, using `rb.get` - NPE while trying to access string
- Not using buffers at all - nothing gets written to stdout/err
- Using just StringWriters instead of combining them with PrintWriters - no change, but [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502974/redirecting-jruby-scriptengine-output-to-a-stringwriter) suggested I do it
- Using another compat version initializing the container - no change
- Using a different LocalVariableBehavior - no change
- Using `rb.setWriter`/`rb.setErrorWriter` instead of `rb.setOutput`/`rb.setError` - no change

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I managed to fix the problem by setting the LocalContextScope of `rb` to THREADSAFE in the constructor and flushing all four writers after the execution.